# why inheritance not working with if statement

Tags: java

I have to calculate the student cost base on a different kind of student. There are two types of student, general student, and dorm student. The dorm student will have extra information compared to the normal student. I have two code, one is work, and the other is not. I don't know why it is not working.

I have two class one is Student class and DormStudent class which is the child class (Student class).

This code is not working (below is code 1)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String selectType = "Are you Dorm (all other interger) or Communiting (1):";
    int inputSelection=checkInputInteger(selectType);
    String inputName = checkInput("Enter your name:");
    int inputYear = checkInputInteger("Enter Year of Entrance:");
    double inputSuppliesCost = checkInputDouble("Enter Supplier cost per year:");
    int inputCreditHour = checkInputInteger("Enter class hour per year:");
    double inputHourPrice= checkInputDouble("Enter the cost class per hour:");


    if(inputSelection==1){
        int inputDurationWeek= checkInputInteger("Enter the number of week stay:");
        double inputWeeklyExpenses = checkInputDouble("Enter weekly expeneses");
        double inputCostRoom =checkInputDouble("Enter the cost of the room or board per week");
        DormStudent student1 = new DormStudent(inputName,inputYear,inputSuppliesCost,inputCreditHour,inputHourPrice,inputDurationWeek,inputWeeklyExpenses,inputCostRoom);

    }else{
        Student student1 = new Student(inputName, inputYear, inputSuppliesCost,inputCreditHour, inputHourPrice);

    }
    student1.printTotalCost();
}
```

I have the error say: Cannot find symbol student1.printTotalCost() (student1) but when I try this is work (below is code 2).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String selectType = "Are you Dorm (all other interger) or Communiting (1):";
    int inputSelection=checkInputInteger(selectType);
    String inputName = checkInput("Enter your name:");
    int inputYear = checkInputInteger("Enter Year of Entrance:");
    double inputSuppliesCost = checkInputDouble("Enter Supplier cost per year:");
    int inputCreditHour = checkInputInteger("Enter class hour per year:");
    double inputHourPrice= checkInputDouble("Enter the cost class per hour:");


    if(inputSelection==1){
        int inputDurationWeek= checkInputInteger("Enter the number of week stay:");
        double inputWeeklyExpenses = checkInputDouble("Enter weekly expeneses");
        double inputCostRoom =checkInputDouble("Enter the cost of the room or board per week");
        DormStudent student1 = new DormStudent(inputName,inputYear,inputSuppliesCost,inputCreditHour,inputHourPrice,inputDurationWeek,inputWeeklyExpenses,inputCostRoom);
        student1.printTotalCost();
    }else{
        Student student1 = new Student(inputName, inputYear, inputSuppliesCost,inputCreditHour, inputHourPrice);
        student1.printTotalCost();
    }
}
```

I just could not understand why the student1 is not recognize after the if statement in code 1. Is this mean the class initialize only work within the if statement?

Comment: what on earth does a condition have to do with inheritance? they are unrelated topics. Your error means that one of your classes does not provide a printTotalCost() method. This has nothing to do with your if statement.

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance. You are trying to use `student1` out of the 2 scopes (both the `if` and `else` case define it) in which it would be possible. It is not the method that cannot be found but the `student1` variable.

Comment: And, just to say: that first block won't even compile, so it's no wonder it won't work.

Comment: `student1` is in the `if` scope, it doesn't exist outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is basically this:

```
if(...){
    DormStudent student1 = new DormStudent();
}else{
    Student student1 = new Student();
}
student1.printTotalCost();
```

`student1` is declared in both block. Each block has its own scope. And variable declared inside those blocks are not accessible outside.

You issue is not the `printTotalCost` method that's not found, it's `student1` on the last line which can't be found.

Quick fix: declare the student before the if block:

```
Student student1;
if(inputSelection==1){
    int inputDurationWeek= checkInputInteger("Enter the number of week stay:");
    double inputWeeklyExpenses = checkInputDouble("Enter weekly expeneses");
    double inputCostRoom =checkInputDouble("Enter the cost of the room or board per week");
    student1 = new DormStudent(inputName,inputYear,inputSuppliesCost,inputCreditHour,inputHourPrice,inputDurationWeek,inputWeeklyExpenses,inputCostRoom);
    student1.printTotalCost();
}else{
    student1 = new Student(inputName, inputYear, inputSuppliesCost,inputCreditHour, inputHourPrice);
    student1.printTotalCost(); // do you really need to print it twice?
}
student1.printTotalCost();
```

Comment: sorry but it not work because  student1 = new DormStudent or student1 = new Student is not working. the error variable student1 is already defined in method main(String[])

Comment: Don't simply add the `Student student1;`line. You also need to remove the declaration of s`student1` in each blocks. Note that in my answer, I change both blocks content. I suggest you have a look on a more basic java tutorial before going further into inheritance concepts.

Comment: Sorry thank you is my fault is work now. I guess I have to redo some of the chapter and go back to inheritance next few days

Answer (score 1):

You must declare, above the `if` statement, a single `student1` variable with the more abstract type (here, `Student` I presume) and assign it in each branch with the actual object.

```
  Student student1;
  if(inputSelection==1){
      int inputDurationWeek= checkInputInteger("Enter the number of week stay:");
      double inputWeeklyExpenses = checkInputDouble("Enter weekly expeneses");
      double inputCostRoom =checkInputDouble("Enter the cost of the room or board per week");
      student1 = new DormStudent(inputName,inputYear,inputSuppliesCost,inputCreditHour,inputHourPrice,inputDurationWeek,inputWeeklyExpenses,inputCostRoom);
      student1.printTotalCost();
  }else{
      student1 = new Student(inputName, inputYear, inputSuppliesCost,inputCreditHour, inputHourPrice);
      student1.printTotalCost();
  }
  student1.printTotalCost();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're having some issues understanding scope. A variable has a certain scope, which means that you can only access it from within the scope it has been declared.

You can find the scope like this: look at the first { that is above the variable, and find the matching } for that one. That is the scope for your variable.

```
public class App { // start scope text
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
    String text = "hey";
}//end scope text right before the }
```

It is slightly different for local variables: variables that are declared within methods. These only exists from where they are created, until the } for the first { one on top.

So for example:

```
if(x < 5) {
    String s = "Hi"; //scope String s starts here
    System.out.println(s);

} //scope s ends just before this }

//if you call s here it no longer exists
```

And a more complex example:

```
public class App {//start scope text

    public void print(){
        System.out.println(text);
        int x = 5; //start scope int x
        if(x < 10){
            int y =23;//start scope y
            System.out.println(y + x + text);
        }//end scope y right before the }
    } //end scope int x right before the }
    String text = "hey";
}//end scope text right before the {
```